# How can I check if the ray is hitting specific objects names?

Tags: unity, c#

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Map : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Camera mapCamera;
    public Text objectWasHit;
    public GameObject mouseOvered;
    public float distanceToHit = 1000;

    private Camera[] cameras;
    private List<GameObject> objectsToHit = new List<GameObject>();

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        cameras = Camera.allCameras;

        GameObject levels = GameObject.Find("_Level");
        foreach (Transform child in levels.transform)
        {
            child.gameObject.AddComponent<UnityEngine.MeshRenderer>();
            objectsToHit.Add(child.gameObject);
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.M))
        {
            if (mapCamera.enabled == false)
            {
                foreach (Camera cam in cameras)
                {
                    cam.enabled = false;
                }
                mapCamera.enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (Camera cam in cameras)
                {
                    cam.enabled = true;
                }
                mapCamera.enabled = false;
            }
        }

        bool rcHit = false;
        Vector3 mouse = Input.mousePosition;
        Ray castPoint = mapCamera.ScreenPointToRay(mouse);
        RaycastHit hit;
        Debug.DrawRay(castPoint.origin, castPoint.direction * distanceToHit, Color.magenta);
        if (Physics.Raycast(castPoint, out hit, distanceToHit))
        {
            rcHit = true;
            if (mouseOvered != hit.collider.gameObject)
            {
                mouseOvered = hit.collider.gameObject;
            }
            objectWasHit.text = mouseOvered.name;
        }

        if (!rcHit && mouseOvered != null)
        {
            mouseOvered = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Now it's hitting every gameobject and then display the object that was hit name:

```
objectWasHit.text = mouseOvered.name;
```

But I want it to display the name of the object/s only if it hit one of the objects in the List objectsToHit.

Comment: Did `if(objectsToHit.Contains(hit.collider.gameObject))...` not do the trick for you?

Comment: _"Now it's hitting every gameobject and then display the object that was hit name:"_  
You should also check out how to work with layers. It will make a huge difference performance wise.   [Unity - Manual: Layers](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Unity Gameobject Tags](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject-tag.html) to assign a tag just before adding them to the list so later you can check the hit only on gameobjects with that tag. First create a new [tag on the editor](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Tags.html)

Answer (score 3):

You can check what the Raycast hit by checking the tag:

```
hit.collider.compareTag("otherThingsTag");
```

or by checking the name:

```
hit.collider.name.Equals("otherThingsName");
```

If you want to check if multiple gameObjects are hit, then you can put them in a List and check what has been hit:

```
List<string> names = new List<string> { "thing1", "thing2" };
foreach (var name in names)
{
  if(hit.collider.name.Equals(name)
  {
     //do stuff
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is helpful but if you want to Raycast to specific object types you can attach a script to the objects that you want to find and look for that script. Something like this:

```
if (hit.transform.gameObject.GetComponent<AIUnit>() != null)
{
    Debug.Log(hit.transform.gameObject.name);
}
```